# Is there a correct way to handle promisified stream error in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to catch an error in the controller and send status(500) to the front-end to let the user know that there is a streaming error. But for some reason the error is not caught and I am sending status(200) to the user. Let me know if i am doing something wrong.

**file - utils.js**

```
import WebSocket from 'ws';
import Twitter from 'twitter-lite';
import ck from 'ckey';

export const stream = (term, clients, twitterStream) => {
  try {
    const twitter = new Twitter({
      // subdomain: 'api', // "api" is the default (change for other subdomains)
      // version: '1.1', // version "1.1" is the default (change for other subdomains)
      version: '2', // version "1.1" is the default (change for v2)
      extension: false, // true is the default (this must be set to false for v2 endpoints)
      consumer_key: ck.TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY,
      consumer_secret: ck.TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET,
      access_token_key: ck.TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN_KEY,
      access_token_secret: ck.TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET,
    });
    let stream = twitter.stream('statuses/filter', { track: term });

    new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
      stream.on('data', function (tweet) {
        console.log('tweet');
        resolve(broadcast(clients, JSON.stringify(tweet)));
      });
      stream.on('error', function (error) {
        reject(error);
      });
    }).catch(function (e) {
      console.log('stream error catch: ', e);
      // throw e;
    });

    twitterStream = stream;
    return twitterStream;
  
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('error from util', error);
    // throw error;
  }
};

const broadcast = (clients, message) => {
  clients.forEach((client) => {
    if (client.readyState === WebSocket.OPEN) {
      client.send(message);
    }
  });
};
```

**controller**

```
import { stream } from './utils.js';  

let twitterStream;  

// Sets search term for twitter stream.
export const setSearchTerm = (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { term } = req.params;
    console.log('setSearchTerm');
    console.log('term: ', term);
    if (twitterStream) {
      console.log('getTweetPause');
      twitterStream.destroy();
    }
    twitterStream = stream(term, req.app.locals.clients, twitterStream);

    res.status(200).json({ message: 'Successful search request' });
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(500).json({ message: error });
  }
};
```

Comment: It's really unclear what you're trying to do with the values from that stream, where  `twitterStream` is declared, and what purpose that promise has in your code.

Comment: code updated for ```twitterStream```

Comment: Ah, so this endpoint lets the user switch the stream. But what does this have to do with promises and streaming errors? I would assume that errors need to be `broadcast` to all clients anyway?

Comment: early I tried it without the ```new Promise``` the code was working but I was not able to catch the error in the controller. So I asked the question on stack overflow and was told that if I want to to catch the error I need to promisify a stream operation

Comment: the idea is that if there is an error coming from the stream I need to let the client know that there is an error

Comment: I guess my real question is if there is a way to pass the error that comes from the stream to the controller so I can send it as status(500) to the client

Comment: "*was told that if I want to to catch the error I need to promisify a stream operation*" - that might have been wrong. Which client do you want to send the error to? The client who initiated the stream switch? The clients that listen to the broadcast? What do you expect to happen with errors that occur long after the `setSearchTerm` switched the stream?

Comment: I need to sent the error to the client that initiated the http request. At this moment the client is receiving status(200) on stream error which is misleading. Because I am letting the user know  that http request was successful but he is not getting the tweets from the stream because there is an error.

Comment: What do you expect to happen with errors that occur long after the setSearchTerm switched the stream?  - I am not expecting any error to occur because whenever I switch the term . the existing stream will be destroyed.

Comment: I don't know that twitter-lite library you're using there. Are you saying it *only* emits an `error` event when the stream fails to open? And is the only way to know that opening the stream succeeded to wait for the first `data` event? I wouldn't want to wait with sending the 200 response until someone sends a tweet.

Comment: in my case I have been hitting my rate limit and getting 420 HTTP errors.

Comment: @Bergi ```new Promise``` actually worked

Answer (score 0):

**file - utils.js**

```
import WebSocket from 'ws';
import Twitter from 'twitter-lite';
import ck from 'ckey';

export const stream = (term) => {
  const twitter = new Twitter({
    // subdomain: 'api', // "api" is the default (change for other subdomains)
    // version: '1.1', // version "1.1" is the default (change for other subdomains)
    version: '2', // version "1.1" is the default (change for v2)
    extension: false, // true is the default (this must be set to false for v2 endpoints)
    consumer_key: ck.TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY,
    consumer_secret: ck.TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET,
    access_token_key: ck.TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN_KEY,
    access_token_secret: ck.TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET,
  });

  let stream = twitter.stream('statuses/filter', { track: term });

  return stream;
};

export const broadcast = (clients, message) => {
  clients.forEach((client) => {
    if (client.readyState === WebSocket.OPEN) {
      client.send(message);
    }
  });
};
```

**controller**

```
import { stream, broadcast } from './utils.js';

let twitterStream;

// Sets search term for twitter stream.
export const setSearchTerm = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { term } = req.params;
    console.log('setSearchTerm');
    console.log('term: ', term);
    if (twitterStream) {
      console.log('getTweetPause');
      twitterStream.destroy();
    }

    const currentStream = stream(term);
    twitterStream = currentStream;

    await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      currentStream.on('data', function (tweet) {
        console.log('tweets: ');
        broadcast(req.app.locals.clients, JSON.stringify(tweet));
        resolve(tweet);
      });

      currentStream.on('error', function (error) {
        reject(error);
      });
    });

    res.status(200).json({ message: 'Successful HTTP request' });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('error catch: ');
    res.status(500).json({ message: error });
  }
};
```